# GridView First Item onClick not working - why?

Tags: android, android-gridview

[image]

This is supposed to be a game to match the number each button has. There will be 12 different numbers and the numbers will be set to random button (2 buttons will have the same number). The player has to click the first button, the button will turn its color to red and if the player click again on another button it will check if it has the same number or not, if yes then both of it will stay in red. For the buttons i am using grid view of buttons. I set all the buttons to black and if i click the button it will change its color to red. The buttons show correctly and all the buttons work perfectly fine except for the first button(on the top left corner), it doesnt turn red but it still does the checking if it has the same number or not.

My code for the getView on BaseAdapter :

```
gridView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return buttons.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
                if(convertView==null) buttons[position] = new Button(activity3.this);
                else buttons[position] = (Button)convertView;

                if(position==12) Collections.shuffle(numbers);
                buttons[position].setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(position%12)));

                buttons[position].setTextSize(0);
                buttons[position].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                buttons[position].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (onClick && position!=indexClick) {
                            onClick = false;
                            String _strClicked = buttons[indexClick].getText().toString();
                            String _strNow = buttons[position].getText().toString();
                            if (_strClicked.equals(_strNow)) {
                                countSuccess++;
                                buttons[indexClick].setEnabled(false);
                                buttons[position].setEnabled(false);
                                buttons[position].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                buttons[position].setTextSize(15);
                            }else {
                                countFail++;
                                buttons[indexClick].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            }

                            if(countSuccess==11){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(activity3.this, activity2.class);
                                intent.putExtra("countFail", String.valueOf(countFail));
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        } else {
                            buttons[position].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            indexClick = position;
                            onClick = true;
                            buttons[position].setTextSize(15);
                        }
                    }
                });

                return buttons[position];
            }
        });
```

For the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity3"
    android:id="@+id/act3_ConstraintLayout"
    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/act3_textViewNICKNAME"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/act3_textViewNilaiMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="HOME                                                          26416058"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried to use android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the Constraint Layout but still the first button on top left corner doesnt turn to red when i click it.

I've searched some references but it still doesnt work:
[Android GridView first button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471625/android-gridview-first-button-not-working)
[OnClickListener not working for first item in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778228/onclicklistener-not-working-for-first-item-in-gridview/22610700#)

Comment: is your getView(..) method fired while initalizing ? otherwise It will initalize onclickListener when u first time click. Then start listening for second time

Comment: @Lucefer i dont really get what you meant by it will initialize onclickListener for the first click. I put the setAdapter method in onCreate. First click on any item will trigger the button to change its color to red, it just doesnt matter whether it is first click or second click any button beside the first button(top left corner) will change its background color to red

Comment: where is declaration and initialization of "indexClick" and "onClick "

Comment: @navylover boolean onClick = false and int indexClick = -1

Comment: @Ricky, it seems every thing perfect. i would like to suggest a test.
make Toast call on every click sequentially clicking on buttons and check what index toast is showing ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan, i did that, when i click the first button, it Toast the position is 0(correct) but still the background color doesnt change to red

Answer (score -1):

plz notice this line:

```
 if(position==12) Collections.shuffle(numbers); 
 //if the length of buttons array is 12,the max index is 11, not 12.
 //position==12 always equals to false.
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it hasnt anything connected with the onclick, ive tested position==11